# Induction in proof of Cauchy's theorem

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading [this note](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cauchypf.pdf) on the proof of Cauchy's theorem. The proof is by induction on $n = \#G$, but I'm having trouble identifying how the induction step is used in Case 1. How does the proof depend on whether or not the theorem is true for $n' < n$, with $p|n'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say correctly, there is no need to use the induction hypothesis in the abelian case. Hence, if we only aim to prove the result for abelian groups, we do not need to do induction.